# Smoothly set margin-top to div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried to smoothly move div(circle), but I can not do it. Div immediately moves to the last point.

I tried to simulate the process of the ball falling.
I used method animate with second param 0, but this did not help me.
How to do it?

```
"use strict";

function calculateH(h, t) {
    return h - ((Math.pow(t, 2)*9.8)/2);
}

/**
 * [getTrip function is calculate Y coordinates for the ball thrown down]
 * @param  {[number]} h         [The height from which the ball falls]
 * @param  {[number]} t         [Time elapsed from the beginning of the fall of the ball]
 * @param  {[number]} interval  [EPS]
 * @param  {[number]} k         [Ratio of height to screen height. It is necessary that the ball fell to the site bottom]
 * @return {[array]}            [Array of Y coordinates. {0, 0.2, 1.2 ... h}]
 */
function getTrip(h, t, interval, k) {
    var calculations = new Array();

    for(t; calculateH(h, t) > 0; t += interval)
        calculations.push((h - calculateH(h, t))*k);

    return calculations;
}

$('document').ready(function() {
    var bol = $('#mycircle');

    var h = 100;
    var t = 0;
    var interval = 0.001; // eps

    /**
     * [k is the ratio of height of the screen to start the ball drop height]
     * @type {[number]}
     */
    var k = ($(document).height()-bol.height()) / h;

    var calculations = getTrip(h, t, interval, k);

    // Problem is there.
    // I want animate of fell ball, but this code just move in last Y coord. 
    calculations.forEach(function(y) {
        bol.css({'margin-top': y+'px'});
    });

    bol.animate({'margin-top': h*k+'px'}, 1); // prees to the bottom
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/82agzc2e/4/

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using a loop, and not animate the `margin-top` directly to last position?

```
bol.animate({'margin-top': calculations[calculations.length - 1]+'px'}, 1000);
```

**[Working example.](https://jsfiddle.net/82agzc2e/5/)**

Comment: Thanks for answer. Because i want simulated physical phenomena. Delay of 1 second will break physical model

Comment: My experiment is fully stimulate the ball drop. It has a height dependent on the time. It is necessary to show acceleration free fall.

Comment: But your propblem is, that an interval of `0.001ms` is not possible. So your animation will be very, very slow. I think this is not what you want. To solve the general question, you have to create you own recursive loop then. Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/82agzc2e/6/ @KonstantinKulakov

Comment: Note: even then it is possible that the browser exit with error for `too mutch recursion`, because there are over 4500 steps in your example.

Comment: Well, i understand it. How to do show/play this animation in real time? i do not want slow animation... Do i may be use canvas or opengl?

Comment: That would be the better solution. But I'm not sure if canvas is that fast too. OpenGL should work.

Comment: Thanks. OpenGL is solution my problem.